# Im attempting to change every 4th or 5th line in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

eg If I have this In a large file of script:

DELAY 10000
STRING 1234
DELAY 16000
ENTER
ENTER
STRING 0000
DELAY 16000
ENTER
ENTER

I wish to remove one enter and replace with DELAY,any help much appreciated.

Comment: so is `ENTER` text or actual line break?

Comment: Can this problem be boiled down to changing any line containing ENTER and followed by ENTER being replaced with DELAY ?

Comment: Thank you Rob,very helpful! your answer has worked correctly, I do not have the rep to up vote you,sorry,ENTER is an the key action, DELAY is the period of time delay

Answer (score 0):

```
Search/Replace
Find What: ENTER\r\nENTER
Replace with: ENTER\nDELAY
Search mode Extended (\n, \r, \t, \0, \x...)
```

result was

```
DELAY 10000
STRING 1234
DELAY 16000
ENTER
DELAY
STRING 0000
DELAY 16000
ENTER
DELAY
```